# Why the angular routing is not working when I build the project?

Tags: angular

I have three angular applications in a workspace, one of the applications imports a module, using lazy loading, from the other two applications, respectively, as seen below:

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { TenantNotFoundComponent } from "./components/tenant-not-found/tenant-not-found.component";

export enum AppRouteName {
    Tenants = 'tenants',
    TenantID = ':tenantID',
    Corporate = '',
    Viewer = 'viewer',
    SuperAdmin = 'super-admin',
    tenantNotFound = '404'
}

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: AppRouteName.Corporate,
        loadChildren: () => import('../../projects/apps/corporate/src/app/core/core.module').then(m => m.CoreModule),
    },
    {
        path: AppRouteName.SuperAdmin,
        loadChildren: () => import('../../projects/apps/super-admin/src/app/core/core.module').then(m => m.CoreModule),
    },
    {
        path: AppRouteName.Tenants,
        children:[
            {
                path: AppRouteName.tenantNotFound,
                component: TenantNotFoundComponent
            },
            {
                path: AppRouteName.TenantID,
                children:[
                    {
                        path: AppRouteName.Viewer,
                        loadChildren: () => import('../../projects/apps/viewer/src/app/core/core.module').then(m => m.CoreModule),
                    },
                    {
                        path: '**',
                        redirectTo: `/${AppRouteName.Corporate}`
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: AppRouteName.Corporate
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Every route works pretty well when I run the project using `ng serve`** but when I compile it using `ng build` and deploy the dist folder to my web server, the only route that works is the first one ('blank' - AppRouteName.Corporate), when I try to enter to the others I get a 404 error from the server.

Here is the dist folder, as you can see there is a chunk for each route (core and ui-kit are libraries, multi-tenant is the app that has the routing above):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvsE4.png)

The modules that are lazily loading all have the same structure, I share it below:

**core.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CoreRoutingModule } from './core-routing.module';
import { CorePageComponent } from './pages/core-page/core-page.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CorePageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CoreRoutingModule,
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

**core-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CorePageComponent } from './pages/core-page/core-page.component';

export enum CoreRoutes {
  Blank = '',
}

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: CoreRoutes.Blank,
        component: CorePageComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CoreRoutingModule { }
```

Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: When you deploy a routed application, you must configure your web server to return index.html when routing to a new route. See this for more information: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration